# hide parent div if child div empty

Tags: jquery, html, hide

If all this yellowrubberbox containes is Office Members but there are no listing for office members ie yellow-content's text is just "Office Members", then i need to hide the yellow-rubber-box..

```
<div class="yellow-rubber-box w-218">
        <span class="yellow-corner left-top">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="yellow-corner right-top">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="yellow-corner left-bottom">
        &nbsp;</span>
        <span class="yellow-corner right-bottom">
        &nbsp;</span>
        <div class="yellow-content"><h2>Office Members</h2>
        Sometimes there is no content inside this div and need to hide the yellow rubber box if this is just equals to "Office Members" which is the heading
        </div>
    </div>
```

why is this not doing it??

```
var YellowBoxContent=$.trim($('.yellow-content').text());   
        if (/Office Members/.test(YellowBoxContent)){      
        $('.yellow-rubber-box').hide();   
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see if an object is empty, but contains children nodes (`h2`), I would guess you need to parse text nodes:

```
$('.yellow-content').contents().each(function() {
    // If it's a text node, and it does not contain non-space
    // characters, hide the `.yellow-rubber-box` it is in
    if (this.nodeType == 3 && !this.textContent.match(/\S/)) {
        $(this).closest('.yellow-rubber-box').hide();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HKdqp/

**Edit**:  After giving this some more thought, there could possibly be no text node, or there could be a text node (space) on either side of the `h2`.  This code is more robust because it checks for any text nodes that contain non-space characters outside of the `h2`:

```
$(function() {
    $('.yellow-content').each(function() {
        var hide = 1;
        $(this).contents().each(function() {
            // If it's a text node, and it contains text, don't hide
            // the parent `.yellow-rubber-box`
            if (this.nodeType == 3 && this.textContent.match(/\S/)) {
                hide = 0;
            }
        });
        if (hide) {
            $(this).closest('.yellow-rubber-box').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HKdqp/2/

If you don't want to mess with text nodes, and want a little shorter code, you can simply remove the `h2`, check if the text left over is empty, and hide the div if it is.  Then you can add the `h2` back:

```
$(function() {
    $('.yellow-content').each(function() {
        var h2 = $(this).find('h2').remove();
        if($(this).text().match(/^[\s\n\r]*$/) ) {
            $(this).closest('.yellow-rubber-box').hide();
        }
        $(this).prepend(h2);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HKdqp/3/

Answer (score 1):

You are testing that the value contains "Office Members".  This will always match.  Why not just test for equality?

```
YellowBoxContent === "Office Members"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xdzka/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would test for other elements within `.yellow-content` besides the h2 instead of converting everything to a string:

```
$(".yellow-content").contents().length > 1
```

`contents` will return elements and text nodes.

Comment: `children` doesn't return text nodes.

Comment: That wasn't clear from the question, but in that case `contents()` will return both.

Comment: The problem I found with this approach (in my own experiments) is that white space counts as a text node, so `<div>  <h2>...</h2>  </div>` will return a length of 3.

Answer (score 0):

you just try this :

```
  var YellowBoxContent=$.trim($('div.yellow-content').text());
  var search = /Office Members/;
  if (search.test(YellowBoxContent))
      {
          $("div[class^='yellow-rubber-box']").hide();
      }
```

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/GWur3/8/

Comment: Other than code formatting, how does this differ from the original solution?  If anything, it's worse, why would you not use the class selector?